# What are the Integration frameworks available.

Tags: spring, frameworks, integration, sca, jbi

Is JBI, SCA also considered an integration framework. What are all the integration framework available.

Answer (score 0):

JBI and SCA fairly different technologies. I will comment on SCA. If by "integration framework" you mean a technology that assists in connecting services, then I would say, yes.

Fabric3 (an SCA runtime) uses those precise terms: http://docs.fabric3.org/